# How to write optimized MySQL search text query, alternative to OR

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

Let say I have following table structure of "some_table" (Currently No Index is used)

1. id_notes: Primary Key, `long`, Auto increment, Unsigned
2. title: `varchar(256)`
3. notes: `varchar(500)`
4. notes2: `text`

I need to return the result if a **keyword** is found in any of the three fields (title, notes, notes2)

Some sample query would be as follows

```
SELECT 
    id_notes, title, notes 
    FROM 
        some_table 
    WHERE 
        title like '%search_keyword%'
        OR 
        notes like '%search_keyword%'       
        OR
        notes2 like '%search_keyword%'
```

How to carry out optimization step by step.

1. Q1: Is it possible to further optimize this query without making any changes to table structure?
2. Q2: Will it help if I create another column "group_text" and concatenate all the three fields in it and search on that group_text field?
3. Q3: What type of `index` would be better if 3 separate fields are used in query?
4. Q4: What type of `index` would be better if a group_text field is used in query (Remember 2 fields are `varchar` and 3rd field is of type `TEXT`)?

Comment: maybe you can use [Full text search functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) for this kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

The leading `%` kills the possibility of using an index.  So does `OR`.  Your query is optimally written.

No, `CONCAT` won't make much difference.

But... Consider using a `FULLTEXT` on the 3 columns.  It will be _much_faster, *if* the restraints of `FULLTEXT` are acceptable.